# CDK AttributeError: module 'aws_cdk.cx_api' has no attribute 'RuntimeInfo'

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Confused on the error of:

```
AttributeError: module 'aws_cdk.cx_api' has no attribute 'RuntimeInfo'
```

```
from constructs import Construct
from aws_cdk import (
    Duration,
    Stack,
    aws_iam as iam,
    aws_sqs as sqs,
    aws_sns as sns,
    aws_sns_subscriptions as subs,
    aws_lakeformation as lakeformation,
    core
)


class TablegrantsStack(Stack):

    def __init__(self, scope: Construct, construct_id: str, **kwargs) -> None:
        super().__init__(scope, construct_id, **kwargs)
        
        # The code below shows an example of how to instantiate this type.
        # The values are placeholders you should change.
        # all_rows_wildcard: Any

        cfn_data_cells_filter = lakeformation.CfnDataCellsFilter(self, "MyCfnDataCellsFilter",
            database_name="test",
            name="MyCfnDataCellsFilter",
            table_catalog_id="189672731068",
            table_name="allergies",
            row_filter=lakeformation.CfnDataCellsFilter.RowFilterProperty(
                all_rows_wildcard=all_rows_wildcard,
                filter_expression="column='1234567890"
            )
        )
```

I believe this an error of the aws_cdk library of core is this because it thinks I am mixing AWS CDK V1 and V2?

Just wondering if anyone has had the same issue.

Thanks

Comment: You are in fact mixing up v1 and v2. CDK v2 doesn't have a `core` module.